# I'm having issues w/12.04 and want to remove it

Tags: 12.04

I built and installed 12.04 about 3 years ago.  I have a 1T hard drive and 4G of ram...nothing special, but it ran great. But then, I ran into an issue where my internet started acting up, so I made some adjustments removing some plug-ins that I felt were unneeded; too many programs junking up my computer. Then I started to have issues with the password...none of these things should have affected one another. But now the issues were starting to build.  However, being the semi-tech savvy person that I am, I researched the issues and nothing. So, I assumed that there must be a bad plug-in that started all of these issues. I have tried to repair and reinstall and now I have the 12.04 LTS as my OS, but now, when I start up, it still has issues.  Start up; logs in automatically, I try to use the internet, it doesn't run at all...it just sits there.  I log out and try to log back in; tells me there's a passwords error.  So it won't let me log in, even though I KNOW that the password is correct and I have to reboot and then it lets me in.  SMH...So, I want to remove 12.04 all together! I wanted to do a dual installation, just bc somethings are easier to deal with in windows than Ubuntu,So I want to remove this OS completely and install 13.10 and Windows. 
please. But, I am getting conflicting information about how to do so.
But, bc I wasn't raised on DOS based systems...I need help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove 12.4 and replace it with 13.10, and if you don't have files which you need to save, the best way to replace it is to clean install ubuntu 13.10. It's like the first time you installed ubuntu 12.04. The detailed instructions on how to do that can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)